# powermock isnt working with grails(IntelliJ) but working with java(Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, grails, powermock

I am trying to powerMock a static method like this:

mockStatic(staticExample.class);
 PowerMockito.doNothing().when(staticExample.class);
 staticExample.addErrorIfNull(any(staticExample.class), any(String.class), any(Object.class),     any(String.class), any(Object[].class)); //line 3

But it is not getting mocked and throwing a null pointer exception at line3

The same code is working when I am using eclipse as IDE.
Is this is an issue due to grails 2.2-powermock 1.5 compatibility?

Comment: Eliminate the IDEs and see if it works with Grails. Then see how to get it working with your IDE of choice.

Comment: I tried with IntelliJ,it is not working.any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, see if you can get it working _outside of the IDE_ - eliminate some variables so you can focus on the real problems

Comment: I tried to run a simple program :PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticMockingExampleClass.class);
        Mockito.when(StaticMockingExampleClass.printString(anyString())).thenReturn(mockedResult);
        Mockito.when(StaticMockingExampleClass.printString(eq(inputString))).thenReturn(mockedResult);
    StaticMockingExampleClass.printString("Adf");
   StaticMockingExampleClass.printString(inputString);
   StaticMockingExampleClass staticMockingExampleClass = Mockito.mock(StaticMockingExampleClass.class);                    But still its not working in IntelliJ with grails 2.2 and powermock 1.5